# Linux Mint 19.2 Cinnamon, when using shortcut, SUPER key seems stucked sometimes

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, cinnamon

I am using Linux Mint 19.2 Cinnamon, and have shortcuts:

```
SHIFT-SUPER-F7    Decrease opacity
SUPER-L    Lock screen
SUPER-D    Show desktop
```

Sometimes, after typing <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>SUPER</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>it works, and the opacity decreases, but screen locks after I hit <kbd>L</kbd>（desktop shows after I hit <kbd>D</kbd>）.

It seems that <kbd>SUPER</kbd> key persists after I type <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>SUPER</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.

And I want to know how to get rid of this.

THANKS.

Comment: Does the problem occur when the keyboard is used on a different computer (assuming it's not part of a laptop) or when used with a different distro?

Comment: Yes, this happens on my laptop. Inspired from you, I had a test it on a computer(not a laptop),  it worked good. Actually I have to press "FN+F7" to make key code of "F7" on my laptop (other "F1 ~ F12" as well). So whenever I get into this trouble, hit "FN+SUPER" will help me get rid of it. Thank you so much. And do you know why this happen?

Comment: I'm guessing it's a hardware issue, but that's just a guess. There's a possible way to tell, though. Correct me if I'm wrong... You tested the same Mint Cinnamon release on a (presumably) desktop computer with the same shortcuts, the laptop with it's built-in keyboard has the prob, and the desktop with it's USB-connected keyboard works fine. If that's the case, you might check if the same prob occurs if the desktop's keyboard is plugged into the laptop and the shortcuts are entered using it. If it does work without probs, I'd say it's likely a physical prob with the laptop's built-in keyboard.

Comment: I will have a try, thanks!